# how to install opencv on mac osx 10.8.2 with macports

Tags: python, macos, opencv, macports

I followed all the directions on this page: http://blog.cingusoft.org/howto-install-opencv-on-mac-os-x-lion

I even installed numpy again but I still get this error. Please please help!

```
import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
import cv2
```

Comment: why the tag macports? The install directions shown do not use macports. ALso how did you install numpy - it is part of the Apple supplied python

Comment: i did sudo port install py27-numpy

Answer (score 0):

The Macports instructions at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port installed 2.4.1 for me (in Snow Leopard).